# PHP Setter dependency with "default dependencies"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, containers

I am currently working on a dependency injection container and I have came across a lot of different types of them (Pimple, Orno/di, Laravel's...) and I plan on doing something close to Pimple. But I still have a question, if I do my DI using setters and getters, is it right to inject "default dependencies" in the constructors of dependent classes? Let me give you an exemple:

So here is my exemple code:

```
<?php

class Dependency
{
    public function print($str)
    {
        echo $str;
    }
}


class Dependent
{
    private $_dependency;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dependency = new Dependency;
    }


    public function setDependency(Dependency $dep)
    {
        $this->_dependency = $dep;
        return $this;
    }

    public function depPrint($str)
    {
        $this->_dependency->print($str);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This way, the user code could directly use the class without knowing its dependencies:

```
$instance = new Dependent;
$instance->depPrint('Hello world');
```

Or if the user code needs the class to use another dependency, it could do just so:

```
$instance = new Dependent;
$instance->setDependency(new Dependency)
    ->depPrint('Hello world');
```

I feel like its convinient as in testing you could replace the dependencies with mock classes and that the user code doesn't have to know anything about the classes dependencies. The biggest downside I found is that it still creates coupling with the default dependencies, but this could be fixed easily by checking if the class exists or not, and if it doesn't exist, then don't inject anything by default. So, are there any downsides to this system, should I use it or should I use something else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the two things:

```
public function __construct($dep = null)
{
    if (is_null($dep)) {
      $this->_dependency = new Dependency;
    } else {
      $this->_dependency = $dep;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw some people saying "Constructor's arguments SHOULD NOT BE OPTIONAL", I don't know if that's true, but anyway your option is interesting, I will see if I can apply it efficiently to my real code. Thank you!